# Google finance to get the price of a stock for a given date

Tags: google-docs-api, google-finance-api

In Google doc, let's say B5 is "GOOG", C1 is 3/18/2016, D1 is 3/19/2016, E1 is 3/20/2016...

How can I get the price for GOOG for each of these dates?

```
I've tired =GOOGLEFINANCE(B5, "price", C1)
```

And I've got a #REF! error: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C5

Comment: Check [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HFhFAPscRTI). I think you have the same issue.